# Change quarkus secure port for insecure-requests=redirect

Tags: https, quarkus

I have configured quarkus like this:

```
quarkus.http.host=localhost
quarkus.http.port=80
quarkus.http.insecure-requests=redirect
quarkus.http.ssl-port=443
```

but when I open `http://localhost` or `http://localhost:80` it redirects to `https://localhost:8443/`

What should I do, how can I change this behaviour to be able to actually point to `:443`?

Answer (score 0):

That configuration is working fine. I used https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/tree/master/local-ssl-usage and changed the config like below

```
quarkus.http.host=localhost
quarkus.http.port=80
quarkus.http.ssl-port=443

quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file-type=JKS
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=../keystore.jks
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password=changeme

quarkus.http.insecure-requests=redirect
```

after I ran **mvn quarkus:dev** here is curl result in my local

```
ozkan@DESKTOP-NF90OD6 MINGW64 ~
$ curl -v http://localhost/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying ::1:80...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.75.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: https://localhost:443/
< content-length: 0
<
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

as log shows, quarkus redirecting the request to 443 port.